# jQuery - Access function return values (x and y)

Tags: jquery, function, events, touch, return

(first off: I'm pretty new to JS and jQuery)

I'm currently working on an image slide, using jQuery. I've made it pretty advanced with tooltips, dynamic height, 100 % width and such. Now my next step is to enable touch slide/swipe.

I found this article (http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/04/18/mapping-mouse-events-and-touch-events-onto-a-single-event/) about making mouse events and touch events as one (ex. mousedown and touchstart equals the same event). In this article the author keeps saying that accessing X and Y values is more simple by using this code (by making "normalizeEvent"). But my problem is that I can't seem to access these at all without getting "undefined".

This is my current code and at the moment I just want to "drag and drop" my slide to do something. But I can't figure out how to get the X value at all..

```
jQuery(new_slide).bind(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function (e){

            // Get current slide position coords
            var position = current_slide.position();

            // X-position for mouse
            var startX  = e.pageX; //this is "undefined"

            // X-position for current slide
            var slideX  = parseInt(position.left);

            // Prevent browser to drag image
            new_slide.bind('dragstart', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

            })

            jQuery(new_slide).bind(TouchMouseEvent.MOVE, function (){

                // Drag slide
                new_slide.css('left', slideX + e.pageX - startX + 'px');

            });

        });

// Release slide
jQuery(new_slide).bind(TouchMouseEvent.UP, function (){

    jQuery(new_slide).unbind(TouchMouseEvent.MOVE);

});
```

Comment: He is defining the mouse event to be a custom event fired through his code - Do you use this code in your file? If so, can you provide a complete code or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Kami sure thing. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xz9dh/ . I really hope you can help me with this. The only thing I need is access to the X and Y coords.